# K8s get back my yaml files from running cluster

Tags: kubernetes

Okay first let me say please don't judge. Believe me, I am kicking myself in the ass.

So I lost my hard disk on my laptop which held the Kubernetes yaml files that I ran against a Kubernetes Cloud cluster. I don't have the latest backup which is the problem.

does anyone know how to get just the yaml I ran against the K8s cloud server. I can get to the cluster and run `kubectl get pod my-pod -o yaml` but of course, it adds a lot of things. I am just looking for the yaml that I ran.

I am stressing here and have learned my lesson. Backup, Backup and verify Backup.

Comment: Backup is one thing but you could also use github for hosting your yamls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this and extend it to your needs:

```
kubectl get [resource type] -n [namespace] [resource Name] -o yaml > [output.yaml]
```

The `-o yaml` will do the job

### [image]

#### Note

You will get some extra information provided by your cloud providers like history, version, and more.

---

#### Lens

https://k8slens.dev/

You can use Lens which will allow you to view & edit your resources so you will be able to copy the YAML from it.[image]